# My plugin, created for Rubymine, is incompatible

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rubymine, intellij-plugin

I've created a plugin for Rubymine. The plugin will not be published for now, for inside use only.
The plugin generates some functions, that I used a lot, by opening generate window with the list of functions. I took example from Intellij Idea for Java projects ( getter, setter, to string ) generators. I created plugin via Gradle.
You can see examples for build-gradle and plugin.xml below.
I am using jar from /build/libs/...
When I am trying to upload my plugin to Intellij from the disk it is works fine.
When I am trying to do the same with Rubymine, I am getting "Plugin is incompatible with this installation". What I am doing wrong? Help please.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.4.16'
}

group 'com.project'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/
intellij {
    version '2019.1'
}
patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes """
      Add change notes here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>"""
}
```

plugin.xml

```
<idea-plugin>
    <id>function_generator</id>
    <name>Function Generator</name>
    <version>1</version>
    <vendor url="">MyCompany</vendor>
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.all</depends>


    <description><![CDATA[
    <p>Plugin to generate most common functions used in Watir for writing automation tests.
    Function are: visible?, click!, visible(text)? .</p>
    ]]></description>

    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <!-- Add your extensions here -->
    </extensions>

    <actions>

        <action id="GenerateVisibleFunctionAction" class="GenerateVisibleFunctionAction" text="Visible">
            <add-to-group group-id="JavaGenerateGroup1" anchor="last"/>
        </action>
        <action id="GenerateClickFunctionAction" class="GenerateClickFunctionAction" text="Click">
            <add-to-group group-id="JavaGenerateGroup1" anchor="last"/>
        </action>
        <action id="GenerateVisibleWithTextFunctionAction" class="GenerateVisibleWithTextFunctionAction"
                text="Visible(text)">
            <add-to-group group-id="JavaGenerateGroup1" anchor="last"/>
        </action>
    </actions>
</idea-plugin>
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

The `<depends>com.intellij.modules.all</depends>` tag in your plugin.xml marks it as compatible only with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. If you want to mark the plugin as compatible with all JetBrains IDEs, change this to `com.intellij.modules.platform`. See [the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks yole for reply, I changed it to <depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends> but I am still getting the same result - is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Try change `<depends>com.intellij.modules.all</depends>` to `<depends>com.intellij.modules.ruby</depends>`

Comment: Thanks. com.intellij.modules.ruby is not recognisable in the <depends>.

Comment: @Alex you can try to refer to this [plugin.xml](https://github.com/JetBrains/ruby-type-inference/blob/master/ide-plugin/resources/META-INF/plugin.xml) and this [build.gradle](https://github.com/JetBrains/ruby-type-inference/blob/master/ide-plugin/build.gradle). This plugin is written specifically for RubyMine, compiles and runs smoothly